# Use of the ~ in CSS

Tags: css

```
    .main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children:hover~li {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Taken from my WordPress theme. What is the meaning of ~li (with the ~ character)?

Thank You

Comment: Steps to find duplicate: Google `css tilde`, first result, done. Please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

The pre ~ p selector means "each P element that is preceded by a PRE element", but, unlike the pre + p adjacent selector, the  element doesn't have to be the direct preceding element.

Therefore this paragraph, too, should be red. Although it's not directly preceded by a , the  is a general previous sibling.

This is a paragraph in a div. Since this paragraph doesn't have the  as a previous sibling (it's more like an uncle; a previous sibling of this paragraph's parent node), it shouldn't be red.

Comment: Copied directly from http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_sibling.html. You shouldn't plagiarise other people's content and call it your own. You should place a link to where you took your information from.